# Generating XML SOAP message in PHP

Tags: php, xml, soap, wsdl

I need help generating XML SOAP message in PHP. I'm using BeSimpleSoap extension. I've tried many different ways to generate SOAP message. 
Message should look like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2015/types/kp" xmlns:gsb="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gsb:SendMessageRequest>
         <gsb:GsbEnvelope>
            <gsb:MessageHeader>
               <gsb:SenderId>1</gsb:SenderId>
               <gsb:ServiceId>126</gsb:ServiceId>
               <gsb:MessageId>c4413331-1cff-11e2-f516-242d656ac4b3</gsb:MessageId>
               <gsb:SenderTimeStamp>2015-05-31T12:00:00</gsb:SenderTimeStamp>
            </gsb:MessageHeader>
            <gsb:Content>
               <gsb:MimeType>aaa</gsb:MimeType>
               <gsb:Data encoding="EMBEDDED">
                     <tns:Upit>
                        <tns:IdPosiljatelja>1</tns:IdPosiljatelja>
                        <tns:TipPoruke>1</tns:TipPoruke>
                        <tns:IdUpita>732262f1-063f-11e2-892e-0812200c9f68</tns:IdUpita>
                        <tns:DatumVrijemeUpita>2015-03-26T15:33:29.371+01:00</tns:DatumVrijemeUpita>
                     </tns:Upit>
               </gsb:Data>
            </gsb:Content>
         </gsb:GsbEnvelope>
      </gsb:SendMessageRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried to generat XML with this:

```
$encodded = new SoapVar("<tns:Upit>
                                <tns:IdPosiljatelja>196</tns:IdPosiljatelja>
                                <tns:TipPoruke>$TipPoruke</tns:TipPoruke>
                                <tns:IdUpita>$UUID</tns:IdUpita>
                                <tns:DatumVrijemeUpita>$date_time</tns:DatumVrijemeUpita>
                            </tns:Upit>", XSD_ANYXML); 

    $par_envelope=array( "GsbEnvelope" =>  
        array( "MessageHeader" => 
            array("SenderId" => "24",
                "ServiceId" => "$ServiceId",
                "MessageId" => $UUID,
                "SenderTimeStamp" => $date_time),
                "Content" => array("MimeType" =>"application/xml","Data" =>array("any"=>$encodded,"encoding"=>"EMBEDDED"))));

    $par_WSDL=array("trace"=>TRUE,
        "exceptions"=>TRUE,
        'location'=>$SERVICE_TEST,
        "local_cert" =>$SOAP_cert,
        'uri'=>$NAMESPACE_URI,
        "passphrase"=>$cert_password,
        "connection_timeout" => 60);

    $client = new BeSimple\SoapClientSoapClient("GSBService.wsdl",$par_WSDL);

    $result=$client->sendMessage($par_envelope);
```

But that only generated part of a XML message that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:SendMessageRequest>
            <ns1:GsbEnvelope>
                <ns1:MessageHeader>
                    <ns1:SenderId>1</ns1:SenderId>
                    <ns1:ServiceId>1</ns1:ServiceId>
                    <ns1:MessageId>34578b73-988a-4727-bee4-a287218cc0a1</ns1:MessageId>
                    <ns1:SenderTimeStamp>2015-10-01T09:07:25+02:00</ns1:SenderTimeStamp>
                </ns1:MessageHeader>
                <ns1:Content>
                    <ns1:MimeType>application/xml</ns1:MimeType>
                    <ns1:Data/>
                </ns1:Content>
            </ns1:GsbEnvelope>
        </ns1:SendMessageRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

EDIT [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5nEOQOUuhptdUlNbkE2VE5kbzg/view?usp=sharing) you can see WSDL and XSD files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the library adds its own namespace prefixes. This is not a problem. In XML the following 3 examples have the same meaning:

- `<ns1:SendMessageRequest xmlns:ns1="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb">`
- `<gsb:SendMessageRequest xmlns:gsb="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb">`
- `<SendMessageRequest xmlns="http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb">`

The XML parser will resolve all 3 to an element node with the local name `SendMessageRequest` in the namespace `http://apis-it.hr/umu/2013/types/gsb`.

So the changed prefix is not a problem. The library can do this to generate/optimize the output.

But, your XML Soap variable is not valid XML. You did not add the namespace definition. If an element has a prefix you will need a namespace definition for this prefix on the element node or one of its ancestors.

```
$encoded = new SoapVar(
  "<tns:Upit xmlns:tns='http://apis-it.hr/umu/2015/types/kp'>
     <tns:IdPosiljatelja>196</tns:IdPosiljatelja>
     <tns:TipPoruke>$TipPoruke</tns:TipPoruke>
     <tns:IdUpita>$UUID</tns:IdUpita> 
     <tns:DatumVrijemeUpita>$date_time</tns:DatumVrijemeUpita>
   </tns:Upit>", 
  XSD_ANYXML
);
```

Comment: I've tried adding namespace like you sad and it didn't work. Also I've tried generating XML with arrays: `$par_envelope=array( "GsbEnvelope" =>  
    array( "MessageHeader" => 
     array("SenderId" => "24",
      "ServiceId" => "$ServiceId",
      "MessageId" => $UUID,
      "SenderTimeStamp" => $date_time),
      "Content" => array("MimeType" =>"application/xml","Data" =>array("any"=> 
      array("Upit"=>array("IdPosiljatelja"=>196,"TipPoruke"=>$TipPoruke,"IdUpita"=>$UUID,"DatumVrijemeUpita"=>$date_time)),"encoding"=>"EMBEDDED"))));`

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to only use array or objects to generate the request that is simply pass as parameter to your SoapClient. And not mix xml strings and Objects.

For example, if ou use a WSDL to php generator, you'll only deal with PHP objects and the XML request will be generated natively by the SoapClient in order to send it to the SOAP Server.

If I can advise you some good WSDL to php generator:

- [wsdltophp.com](https://www.wsdltophp.com)
- [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator)

Comment: When using www.wsdltophp.com I got this error: `SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: can't import schema from GSBSchema.xsd` When using object only I got this error: Fatal error: `Uncaught SoapFault exception: [env:Client] Internal Error in C:\xampp\htdocs\NIAS\HZZO-OKP-SOAP-Count-OIB.php:118`

Comment: Did you try generating a package with PackageGenerator? If your WSDL includes non reachable schema (such as ../GSBSchema.xsd), this is normal that wsdltophp.com generates an error. Otherwise, fix the WSDL by putting the absolute url to ../GSBSchema.xsd

Comment: I got error after I successfully generated PHP with wsdltophp.com: `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'var/wsdltophp.com/storage/wsdls/0d221148117ab117f649a22ae701885a/wsdl.xml' : failed to load external entity "var/wsdltophp.com/storage/wsdls/0d221148117ab117f649a22ae701885a/wsdl.xml"`

Comment: You MUST read the sample-pkp.php file to make it work, so you MUST use your own path to the WSDL